# Otherwise com redirectTo para outra url que não faça parte do Single page application

Tags: angularjs, route, angular-routes

Por exemplo, nas rotas abaixo:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: "../views/dashboard.html",
        controller : "dashboardCtrl"
    }).when('/cadastro', {
        templateUrl: "../views/signin.html",
        controller : "signInCtrl"
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/login'
    });
})
```

Eu uso o `otherwise` para `/login`, o que tem como consequência a rota:

```
http://www.myapp.com/rotaAtual/#/login
```

Já que é a rota padrão da *sigle page application*, mas caso eu queira mudar para uma rota como:

```
http://www.myapp.com/login
```

é possível?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Você terá que criar um controller, quer por javascript faça redirect para a url externa, algo assim:

```
.otherwise({
    controller : function(){
       window.location.replace('http://www.myapp.com/login');
    }, 
    template : "<div></div>"
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou bem como eu queria. Mas, uma coisa, ele só funciona com a declaração do template?

Comment: Cara, faço a mesma pergunta acima, por que você utilizou o ``template``?  O que ele significa nessa situação? Links?